# Getting an error when trying to execute procedure within a procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to write a procedure that executes another procedure within it, but I'm getting this error

> Incorrect syntax near '@PRIMARY_AM'

but I get this error only with the variables that have a `CAST()` OR `ISNULL()` OR `REPLACE()` function. If I comment out the line with `@PRIMARY_AM` it will then say

> Incorrect syntax near 'ISNULL'

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  [dbo].[RUN_PROCESS]
   @PRIMARY_NO VARCHAR(20) = NULL,
   @COMBINED_AM INT = NULL,
   @PRIMARY_BOR VARCHAR(40) = NULL,
   @PRIMARY_AM INT = NULL,
   @SECONDARY_AM INT = NULL,
   @SECONDARY_DT SMALLDATETIME = NULL,
   @PRIMARY_CD VARCHAR(10) = NULL,
   @O_ID INT OUTPUT    

AS

EXEC dbo.LINK_PROCESS
    @PRIMARY_NO = @PRIMARY_NO,
    @COMBINED_AM = CAST(@PRIMARY_AM + @SECONDARY_AM AS VARCHAR),
    @PRIMARY_BOR = REPLACE(ISNULL(@PRIMARY_BOR, ''), '''',' '),
    @PRIMARY_AM = CAST(ISNULL(@PRIMARY_AM, 0) AS VARCHAR),
    @SECONDARY_AM = CAST(ISNULL(@SECONDARY_AM, 0) AS VARCHAR),
    @SECONDARY_DT = CAST(@SECONDARY_DT AS VARCHAR),
    @PRIMARY_CD = ISNULL(@PRIMARY_CD, ''),
    @O_ID = @O_ID OUTPUT;
```

If I remove those functions `CAST()`, `REPLACE()` and `ISNULL()` then I can execute the query without a problem. I don't know why this isn't working.

I'm using SQL Server 2005

Comment: Stored procedures, accept parameters (variables and constants) but **not** expressions. You need to do all casting before calling your SP.

Comment: That makes sense and now it works! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution to my problem, thanks to Alex and his comment under my question

> Stored procedures, accept parameters (variables and constants) but not
>   expressions. You need to do all casting before calling your SP. – Alex

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  [dbo].[RUN_PROCESS]
   @PRIMARY_NO VARCHAR(20) = NULL,
   @COMBINED_AM INT = NULL,
   @PRIMARY_BOR VARCHAR(40) = NULL,
   @PRIMARY_AM INT = NULL,
   @SECONDARY_AM INT = NULL,
   @SECONDARY_DT SMALLDATETIME = NULL,
   @PRIMARY_CD VARCHAR(10) = NULL,
   @O_ID INT OUTPUT

AS

DECLARE @COMBINED VARCHAR
SET @COMBINED = CAST(@PRIMARY_AM + @SECONDARY_AM AS VARCHAR)
DECLARE @PRIM_BOR VARCHAR(40)
SET @PRIM_BOR = REPLACE(ISNULL(@PRIMARY_BOR, ''), '''',' ')
DECLARE @PRIM_AM VARCHAR
SET @PRIM_AM = CAST(ISNULL(@PRIMARY_AM, 0) AS VARCHAR)
DECLARE @SEC_AM VARCHAR
SET @SEC_AM = CAST(ISNULL(@SECONDARY_AM, 0) AS VARCHAR)
DECLARE @SEC_DT VARCHAR
SET @SEC_DT = CAST(@SECONDARY_DT AS VARCHAR)
DECLARE @PRIM_CD VARCHAR(10)
SET @PRIM_CD = ISNULL(@PRIMARY_CD, '')

EXEC dbo.LINK_PROCESS
    @PRIMARY_NO = @PRIMARY_NO,
    @COMBINED_AM = @COMBINED,
    @PRIMARY_BOR = @PRIM_BOR,
    @PRIMARY_AM = @PRIM_AM,
    @SECONDARY_AM = @SEC_AM,
    @SECONDARY_DT = @SEC_DT,
    @PRIMARY_CD = @PRIM_CD,
    @O_ID = @O_ID OUTPUT;
```